# BOOL / VARIANT_BOOL OLE Interface error on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, activex, ole

Under Visual Studio 2010, I'm developing a 64-bit ActiveX control in C++.  I ran into a data corruption error that seems to be rooted in the Microsoft library.    I can't believe such an obvious bug would exist in the library after all these years, so is my analysis correct?

In the .idl file, I have defined a Boolean property:

```
 [id(44) , helpstring("Enable Proximity detection")] VARIANT_BOOL ProxEnabled
```

In the header file, the property is defined:

```
void OnProxEnabledChanged(void);
VARIANT_BOOL m_ProxEnabled;
```

And OLE connected here:

```
DISP_PROPERTY_NOTIFY_ID(CmyCtrl, "ProxEnabled", dispidm_ProxEnabled, m_ProxEnabled, OnProxEnabledChanged, VT_BOOL)
```

The problem comes in my code when I set the property from C#, and it corrupts nearby memory:

```
  myControl.ProxEnabled = true;
```

The root of the problem is the data exchange sequence in Microsoft's library oledisp1.cpp:

```
case VT_BOOL:
    *(BOOL*)pProp = (V_BOOL(pArg) != 0);
    break;
```

Note that pProp is being cast as a pointer to **BOOL**, not **VARIANT_BOOL**.  BOOL is defined as an int, while VARIANT_BOOL is defined as a short.

In WinDef.h:

```
typedef int                 BOOL;
```

In file WTypes.h:

```
/* 0 == FALSE, -1 == TRUE */
typedef short VARIANT_BOOL;
```

Answer (score 2):

This methods maps to C++ types, not automation types.  Compare the VT_BSTR case, it maps BSTR to CString.  Your m_ProxEnabled variable should be BOOL instead of VARIANT_BOOL.  Also indicated in this [MSDN Library page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xh3dsbd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), note the "Property type" column.

Reflection is nice, isn't it?

Comment: So, it's really an error in the 'Add Property' Wizard?  The only available BOOL type property is VARIANT_BOOL, which automatically creates the member as type VARIANT_BOOL.

Comment: That's not a kind of wizard I've ever used, not sure.  The automation type should be VARIANT_BOOL, the backing variable you use through the macro should be BOOL.  Does the wizard actually generate the DISP_PROPERTY_NOTIFY_ID macro?  Then post to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Yes, this was all wizard generated.  I'll file with connect.microsoft.com.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was running into the same problem with a Heap Corruption when using the control in a WinForms application. Who'd expect that the wizard is wrong!?